# Use inbound operation for outbound in OSB proxy

Tags: osb

I have created business and proxy services based on same wsdl file, and the wsdl has 4 methods for which i have created the branch node to call 4 methods, and in each branch node, i just used routing with option "Use inbound operation for outbound", as there is no data enrichment needed in OSB.

So this flow will accept the request and send the same request to my business service which i have created using same wsdl?

or

Do we need to modify the request and response XML to make this flow work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your osb architecture have only 1 layer based on same wsdl file, you don't need modify anything and that will work like simple pass route.

Option **Use inbound operation for outbound** means that your osb engine will use same operation in your business service.

The same result will be achieved when the checkbox is unchecked and the corresponding operation will be selected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

That means if any client calls my Proxy, then same request will be sent to Business and get the response and send it back without any changes in it.

I'm new to OSB so please help me in understanding the flow.